# Theming with white text and black background, and reverse

Tags: sharepoint-online, theme

Hello I'm new to SharePoint, I created a theme using [this tool](https://fluentuipr.z22.web.core.windows.net/heads/master/theming-designer/index.html). And Exported it using PowerShell

Primary: #6ebe49

Text color: #ffffff

Background color: #000000

The problem is, one of the section background shadings is white background and white text. Is there a way to make that background shading white background and black text?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, when you use Fluent UI Theme Designer to create a modern theme, there is no option to change the color of some texts, it is an overall setting.

Comment: I see, is there a way to create a theme that I can modify the background shadings?

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer:
Use the `prefers-color-scheme` CSS media feature.
See here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

Examples:
Create two css rules as per below and put them at the bottom of the last style sheet that is loaded (or put them into the HTML - below the style sheets) so as to override:

***Dark Theme***
`@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { :root { --primary-color: #CCCCCC; --background-color: #000000; --text-color: #FFFFFF; } }`

***Light Theme***
`@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) { :root { --primary-color: #CCCCCC; --background-color: #FFFFFF; --text-color: #000000; } }`

Comment: Using the `prefers-color-scheme` CSS media feature might work if your OS or browser has been set to 'Dark' mode, however doesn't work if a SharePoint site has been set to use a dark *theme*.